# How to compress an NTFS folder using Linux tools

Tags: linux, ntfs

I'm facing a problem, my Windows 7 `C:\Windows\winsxs` folder is growing very large(20GB), and I'd like to compress it using Explorer built-in tool(Folder property -> Advanced -> compress), but you know, Windows actually do not allow me to do that because those winsxs files are protected by a special user named **TrustedInstaller** . So I'd like to do it in Linux. Internet searching show some hint about ntfs-3g, but I can't find a concreting example doing NTFS folder compressing, so I'd like to ask here.

Assume that my booted into Knoppix Linux and Windows C: partition has been mounted to `/mnt/winc`, then what command should I use to achieve the goal.

Or is there a way to do it without a Linux environment?

Comment: [See here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/data-compression/) for details on compression. That being said: This folder contains hard links. Use Windows to modify it, if you really want to. There are guides available.

Comment: Modifying `WinSxS` outside of Windows is dangerous.  It can leave your system in a state where it cannot repair itself.  While NTFS-3G is stable its still unofficial.  You should not be modifying a Windows system disk within Linux unless you are 100% positive you shutdown the system instead of hibernation/suspended/ect. it.  There are ways to nuke that folder, if you are that cramped for space, you might as well do that.

Comment: Thank you. I know that, I have periodic whole partition backup and I know I should never modify a disk from a hibernated state.

Comment: You can also clean the WinSxS folder a bit **from within Windows**, a much safer approach than from Linux. You forgo reverting from some Windows and application updates by the cleanup, though. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx. [It seems MS assumed storage was virtually infinite, and then tablets with small SHDD were invented.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible without Linux and I always do it after creating a new installation. I just did it with a Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2 installation which is now 4.6GB after compression.

The way I do it is to complete the installation, then reboot back into the installation media (either USB stick or DVD). Once it has loaded, you don't have to proceed with the actual installation dialogs unless you're trying to compress a drive that needs a driver before it's available to the installer. You'll know if you do, because then you will already have provided it manually during the initial install. If this doesn't make sense to you, just ignore this part and skip to the next paragraph. If you need to do this, just proceed with the installation steps up until selecting the partition to install to, where you should load your driver.

In either scenario, press `Shift+F10` to bring up a command prompt. Now find out which drive is the installation drive. It probably won't be C: as that's most likely the installer drive. You'll have to start at the first drive and list its contents until you find the right one. That is, type `C:` and enter, then `dir` and enter, and examine the output. Then proceed with `D:`, `E:`, etc. until you find it. The drive you're looking for will have the "Users" and "Windows" and "Program Files" folder an so on, and if you have more than one Windows installation on the computer, you can look at the reported free space on the drive to guess which one it is. In my latest installation, the Windows drive was drive F.

Once you've determined the drive, you can use `compact.exe` to compress the drive. You won't have to worry about accidentally compressing unsafe files since `compact` will take care of this automatically. It won't compress the boot loader, for instance, or the pagefile. Now, the quickest way to do it, that is also less space-saving is this, which is the equivalent of using Explorer (except that in this command prompt, you will compress all files that can be compressed). Make sure you've navigated to the drive you want to compress (F: in my latest case), and type this:

`compact /c /i /s:\`

`/c` just means compress. `/i` is to ignore errors. You will get errors, e.g. you cannot compress `Documents and Settings` in Windows 10 because it actually isn't a folder, but a junction that points to `Users`. Without `/i`, `compact` would stop after such an error. `/s:\` means process everything in the directory `\` (where you are, i.e. the root of the drive), and all the subdirectories in it.

As mentioned, this way of doing it will work just the same as in Explorer, except it will compress many more files that Explorer won't because you don't have access to them and/or they are in use. On my current installation, it resulted in a 1.7:1 compression ratio.

If, however, you wanna go a little more extreme with space-saving, there's a flag, `/exe` which tells `compact` to use more efficient compression that is meant for write-once-read-often type of files, usually executables (e.g. `explorer.exe`), hence the name. It will compress *all* files with the chosen algorithm, though, so it saves space on all files, not just executables. The most efficient algorithm is `lzx`, which when applied to my installation yielded a compression ratio of 2.4:1 (actually, I wanna say 2.7:1, but I can't quite remember, but it's significantly more efficent than the default). It requires you to do two runs, though - these:

`compact /c /i /f /exe:lzx /s:\`

And then:

`compact /c /i /s:\`

Okay, so why two runs, you may ask. That's because when you use the `/exe` flag you're telling `compact` to use a non-standard compression algorithm that NTFS won't apply by default - you have to run this command to compress with that. By extension, it therefore refuses to mark folders as compressed since it cannot automatically compress new files with `lzx`, so while the first `compact` command compresses all files on the drive very efficiently, it leaves all folders without a compression flag, which means any new or changed files won't be compressed, either.

Note the extra addition of the `/f` flag. In case you already have some compressed files on the drive (maybe you compressed your Documents folder or something like that), this will force already-compressed files to be recompressed with the `lzx` algorithm.

The second command is basically the same command as the first one further up, but because we don't use `/f` to force anything to be compressed that already is compressed, the effect here is that it'll skip all the files we just compressed with `lzx`, but mark all folders as compressed, so that in the future, new and modified files will be automatically compressed as well.

In short, the first command compresses all files very efficiently, and the second one marks all folders as compressed, so that future files are compressed, too.

I should note that first of all, this type of compression isn't supported in all implementations of NTFS. For example, in my Linux Mint 20.2 Live stick, files compressed like this won't be read at all. AFAICT, read support exists for more recent versions of the open-source `ntfs-3g` driver, but it may no be accessible yet in your distro. I don't know if the new `ntfs3` native Linux driver supports it, either. On the Microsoft side, it appears it might be only Windows 10 and up, too, so you may not be able to read such a drive from Windows 7 or 8, for instance. Second of all, because Windows won't automatically compress new and modified files with these more efficient algorithms, remember that any compressed file that is modified in the future will be recompressed with the less efficient default algorithm. If you're Windows 10'ing or Windows 11'ing it, though, everything will work. It's just worth considering.

Hope this helps :)

PS: This can of course be done at any time on any existing installation, I'm just mentioning new installs here because it's become a habit of mine to do it immediately after a new installation.

EDIT: A little update after I finished setting up this new system of mine, and now re-ran all this from the Windows installer prior to enabling BitLocker. The method here, again, was to use `/lzx:exe` first, then do a second run to mark all folders for compression as well. This works great (saved an extra 4 GB on the system drive after compression (I had used the default compression algorithm first as I wanted to be able to modify the filesystem with Linux, so this is 4 GB extra savings compared to the default compression algorithm)), but I was then confused since I noticed in Windows Explorer that a lot of files didn't look compressed. That is to say, they weren't colored (I enabled "Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color" in view settings, and a lot of files weren't blue). I messed about with `compact` in an administrative command prompt, and was unable to change this. I then discovered that it's actually just classical Microsoft incompetence - Windows Explorer doesn't itself understand these new `EXE` compression algorithms, so it won't show the files as blue, and if you check their properties it'll also not have a checkmark in the compression box under advanced. BUT, it'll show the correct sizes in regular size vs. size on disk, so the "used space" number will be lower. Jebus! XD

Comment: Thanks, a geek's answer with so many details. The key is running compact.exe from a WinPE environment. Although not tried yet, I think you statements are quite accurate.

Comment: Quite welcome :) I've added an edit to the end that's worth reading ;)

Answer (score 2):

The steps are:

1. Mark the directory for compression
2. Move the files to a temporary location
3. `cp -a` the files back to their original destination to trigger the compression

(By default ntfs-3g enables [mount option `compression`](https://manned.org/ntfs-3g).)

---

```
# Mark a directory for compression
setfattr -h -v 0x00000800 -n system.ntfs_attrib_be directory-name

# On small-endian computers when above is not possible
setfattr -h -v 0x00080000 -n system.ntfs_attrib directory-name
```

Note the caveats though (from the [ntfs-3g](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/compression.html) page):

> When the mount option `compression` is set, files created in a directory marked for compression are created compressed. They remain compressed when they are moved (by renaming) to a regular directory in the same volume, and data appended to them after they have been moved are compressed. Conversely files which were present in a directory before it is marked for compression, and files moved from a directory not marked for compression are not compressed. Copying a compressed file always decompresses it, just to compress it again if the target directory is marked for compression.

---

For new volumes, check out the  `-C` option in `mkfs.ntfs`.